# cannot save workspace image upon the exit in R

Tags: r, rstudio, onedrive

In window 10, 64bit, I am using Rstudio Version 1.1.456 which is directly installed via Anaconda.
If I choose to save the workspace image upon exit, an error message will show up like

```r
Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/yinco/OneDrive/??/.RDataTmp', probable reason 'Invalid argument'
Error: Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file.remove(outfile) :
  cannot remove file 'C:/Users/yinco/OneDrive/??/.RDataTmp', reason 'Invalid argument'
Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/yinco/OneDrive/??/.RDataTmp', probable reason 'Invalid argument'
Error: Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file.remove(outfile) :
  cannot remove file 'C:/Users/yinco/OneDrive/??/.RDataTmp', reason 'Invalid argument'
Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/yinco/OneDrive/??/.RDataTmp', probable reason 'Invalid argument'
Error: Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file.remove(outfile) :
  cannot remove file 'C:/Users/yinco/OneDrive/??/.RDataTmp', reason 'Invalid argument'
```

I try to unlink the one Drive and cannot find its existence.

many thanks if someone can resolve my problems

Comment: I've suggested an edit to your question, but in the future please read how to [format questions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). While some of it is aesthetic, your original question looked like a big jumble, making it incredibly difficult to read. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, does this link help? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-onedrive-for-business-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa